# Why isn't this jQuery script replacing the video declaration with the GIF declaration on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, user-interface

I'm writing a jQuery script to detect when a user visiting my website is on an iOS device, and when they are, to switch the background of the website from a video to a GIF, since .mp4 and .webm files aren't supported on the iOS version of Safari. The script uses modernizr.js and uisearch.js as supporting files. The script is directly included in the HTML, not as a separate file. Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {

      ('.video-background').remove();
      ('body').prepend('<img src="./index_files/Test_cut_GIF.gif" id="backgroundimage" class="video-background">');
    }
  });
```

The HTML that it is attempting to change looks like this:

```
<body  div="main" class="html front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-16 node-type-panel role-1 lightbox-processed">
  <div class="video-background">
    <video id="video" preload="none" poster="./index_files" autoplay="autoplay" loop="true">
      <source src="./index_files/Test_cut_soundless_WEBM.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="./index_files/Test_cut_soundless_MP4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
```

It's trying to change it to this:

```
<body  div="main" class="html front not-logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-16 node-type-panel role-1 lightbox-processed">
  <img src="./index_files/Test_cut_GIF.gif" id="backgroundimage" class="video-background">
```

I'm a very beginner programmer, and if someone could shed some light on what's not working here, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In calling remove and prepend, you have missing `$` at the start

Here:

```
('.video-background').remove();
('body').prepend('<img src="./index_files/Test_cut_GIF.gif" id="backgroundimage" class="video-background">');
```

Replace it to:

```
$('.video-background').remove();
$('body').prepend('<img src="./index_files/Test_cut_GIF.gif" id="backgroundimage" class="video-background">');
```

I hope this helps :)